# How do I use send_long_data for a MySQL JSON column?

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I am currently storing JSON data in a gzipped LONGBLOB column. I want to change this column to a JSON column so that O can use the JSON functions in MySQL.

However, when I tried to insert a row using MySQL with a JSON column, I realised that the insert_id was always 0 and all the inserts failed. I then checked the PHP MySQLi documentation and realised that send_long_data (which I was using to send the JSON data) is only usable for TEXT and BLOB columns.

Is there an alternative to send_long_data which works for JSON columns? Sending the JSON data using bind_param and a string would not work as I believe most of my data would exceed max_allowed_packet.

Comment: My Goodness. Using JSON functions on JSON data so huge that it would exceed the max_allowed_packet. What did your database to you that you want to torture it *so* cruelly?

Comment: Why would you want to store huge gzipped json in the database? Just store it as files in your filesystem. MySQL is for relational data.

Comment: I want to store draft posts. Normally posts are stored in a table, which is linked to other tables such as a picture table with foreign keys. However, I don't want to link up the draft posts table with all these other tables. So my frontend just sends the entire draft over AJAX (gzipped on client side) to my REST API which dumps it in a column. However, the downside is that I cannot read the data in the draft post on server side unless I ungzip and json_decode it. I read about the MySQL JSON functions and thought it might help to speed up my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it's bad practice:

Create a TEXT field, insert data into it, and then use UPDATE to copy the data from the TEXT field to JSON, then clear the TEXT field through UPDATE.